# Physical interpretations of compressibility definitions

Tags: condensed-matter, partition-function

I can compute the thermodynamic compressibility in terms of a partition function as

$$ \kappa = \frac{1}{\langle n \rangle^2} \frac{\partial n}{\partial \mu} = - \frac{1}{\langle n \rangle^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \mu^2}$$

and I know that the limits of $\kappa \mapsto \infty $ is a perfect metal and $\kappa \mapsto 0$ is an incompressible insulator.

However, I can also define
$$ \langle n \rangle = \frac{1}{\langle n \rangle^2} \int \text{d} \omega A(\omega, \mu) n_F({ \omega, \mu}) $$

where $A(\omega, \mu)$ is the electron spectral function and $n_F({ \omega, \mu}) $ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution.

This gives a new equation
$$ \kappa = \frac{1}{\langle n \rangle^2} \left(\int \text{d} \omega  \frac{\partial A(\omega, \mu)}{ \partial \mu} n_F({ \omega, \mu}) + \int \text{d} \omega  \frac{\partial n_F({\omega, \mu}) }{ \partial \mu} A(\omega, \mu) \right) $$

Are there physical intuitions for what these two quantities are or easy ways to estimate them if I don't have a closed form expression of $A$?